# Регулярное выражение для js

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Помогите с регулярным выражением, пожалуйста.

Минимальное количество символов - 10, максимальное - 250, буквы русские, латинские, запятая, пробел и точка, остальное не валидно.

Comment: https://regex101.com/
Вдруг пригодится

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\,\s\.]{10,250}$/
```

Comment: `\s` - все пробельные символы, а не только пробел. И русский алфавит вы видимо не знаете (в разрезе регулярок).

Comment: вы забыли про ё

Comment: акрыт по причине того, что не по теме участником PashaPash♦ 31 июл в 8:10.

Comment: ты не по теме по жизни